# Is saving sensitive data into Bundle an issue?

Tags: android, security, android-lifecycle

I have a piece of sensitive data (encryption key) in Activity private variable. When my Activity is paused or stopped, I would like to save this into Bundle in order to be able to recreate prev activity state from onResume.

Is this safe? Can the saved instance be accessed on e.g. rooted phone and is it saved in an encrypted or plaintext form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle will be saved to memory, which is not encrypted. However, no other application knows the address of the bundle's contents, so it is highly unlikely that an outsider could glean this information even if they could access your application's memory.

Comment: Are you sure it is not saved into some temp local file? Why eat up memory while the app is inactive?

Comment: The app is still allocated memory while it is paused and stopped. This does not go away until it is completely destroyed. At that point, I don't think there's any way to get back the original bundle, which would indicate it isn't stored temporarily anywhere on the disc. The only way I can imagine it would be stored on the disc is if the system destroyed your application and saved the bundle for the next restore, but even then it would be very hard for an outsider to find and access it.